# Adding "using namespace..." causes compilation error [expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or...] in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is strange, whenever I add "using namespace ..." to a header file it craps out

```
 error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'namespace'
```

on me.

I remove it, and try to use namespace operator ::, like cv (for OpenCV) it says

```
error: expected ')' before '<' token
```

My header file has .hpp extension, and implementation file has .mm. It looks like xcode 4 is trying to compile it as a traditional C file. Is that right?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your source file type in Utilities -> File Inspector panel (⌘⌥+1). Check "Identity and type" section. It has "File type" drop down there. Check the appropriate file type there and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks. I checked, and it says "Default - C++ header", which means it was okay. Is there any chance xcode may have freaked out somehow? any ideas?

Comment: Not really. I haven't used Xcode for anything except for Objective-C development. Can't help you with anything else. Although you CAN check detailed command executed to parse the file in question.

Comment: k, just got xcode 4 and the way you see build result is so different from 3.2. I looked at the error log and the problem was another .m file shoulda been .mm instead. God damn 3 hours of my life. There's more problems now. I manually deleted all the files in "SharedPrecompiledHeaders" because I thought some cache was out of date. Now I run the simulator and it says "trouble ahead." You know if I have to re-recreate the project to re-generate the headers, or any better ways?

Comment: Try cleaning (⌘⇧+k) and building again. It cleans the precompiled headers and they are recompiled once the project is built again.