# C++ and Objc Build Errors

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I have been trying to add MobileSynth to my application for some time now and I am only running into errors.

I have followed the steps [here](http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/) which explain how to add a project into another one.

When I compile, both projects are compiled correctly without errors, but the moment I try import the code into my objective C source code I get a large number of errors.

This is a screenshot of the errors.
[image]

[image]

Im sure there are more errors than these as there seems to be something wrong with the dependencies.

I also approved Xcodes recommendation to convert the project 2 (containing the objective C viewcontrollers with .mm extensions and the .cpp files) from an old 3.something version to the version 4 project type, and made the snapshot. Didnt seem to change anything.

I am not sure how to solve these issues. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you changed your `main.m` to `main.mm`?

Comment: Do you have all of the necessary frameworks and libraries in place? Check your build phases in both projects and make sure that the composite contains all of the files.

Comment: I just changed my main to .mm and it doesnt remove the errors. The thing is if I dont import project 2 source in my project 1, both projects compile fine. When I #import "mobilesynthViewController.h" from project 2 into project 1 (project 2 has viewcontrollers with .mm files that use .cpp classes) I get loads of errors in the .h files of these project 2 .mm files.

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with `namespace` (as Inder suggests). All the other errors are caused by incorrect parsing of your file caused by this error.

Comment: What I dont get is that it works in the project 2 as is. When I import one of the viewcontrollers of project 2 into project 1 I get all these errors. The namespace code looks like this: using namespace synth { class Controller; }

Comment: You must be missing a library or framework necessary for correct parsing of `namespace`. Or you don't have a compiler flag that you should have... Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5289144/1487063

Comment: Actually, now even without including the viewcontroller from project 2 it has build errors. I have all of the frameworks that project 2 has, within project 1

Comment: Is this header file included by any other non Objective C++ files? Since it contains C++, any other file that imports it will also need the .mm extension, even if it doesn't contain any C++ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `using namespace` instead of `namespace`.

Comment: The files that use the c++ code are .mm. I also tried to change the .m file of the class where I import the files into to .mm but it didnt change anything.

Comment: I changed it to using namespace, so it looks like this using namespace synth { class Controller; }  I get errors from the LLVM 3.1 compiler saying expected namespace name.

Comment: @Helium3, the namespace code in your original post was correct. It's forward declaring classes that live in a namespace, which you then later declare with `synth::Controller* controller_`. No need for any `using namespace`

Answer (score 0):

You're aware that files that use C++ need the .mm extension. You also need to consider import dependencies. Since this header contains C++, any other file that imports it will also need to have the .mm extension. I'm almost positive that's what's happening to you.

I generally try to keep C++ quarantined to the implementation files for this very reason.

Also, for clarification on previous advice:

```
// Correct
namespace synth { class something; }

// Incorrect
using namespace synth { class something; } 

// Optional
namespace synth { class something; }
using namespace synth;
```